# "Best of Stack Exchange" newsletter

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

There are some excellent posts on various sites - both questions and answers; Of course, for the more technical it's harder to appreciate them but I would love to have a newsletter of "the best of SE".

Couple of posts I would like to see there:

- [Single parent takes many sick days](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/65867/single-parent-takes-many-sick-days)
- [Are the luggage storage lockers at Brussels-Midi still available for use in April 2016 after recent security clampdowns?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67296/are-the-luggage-storage-lockers-at-brussels-midi-still-available-for-use-in-apri/67340#67340)

Because someone personally checked the place for an answer and that's just the last two days.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your request to be more focused on the newsletter part. If I was mistaken feel free to roll back.

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry for not finding it.

Comment: No problem, wasn't trivial to find.